# How to configure Proxy in Locust for FastHTTPUser approach

Tags: locust, fasthttp

How to configure Proxies in Locust for FastHTTPUser Approach.
It is working fine for HTTPUser approach as given below but same is not working for FastHTTPUser approach.

```
proxies = {
          "http": "my.company.cmm:80",
          "https": "my.company.com:443",
    }
    
self.get.client(url, proxies=proxies)
```

How to verify the same proxy approach in FastHTTPUser

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Proxies are not supported by FastHTTPUser client among other features available only in the HTTPUser that it's requests based